# Maven error: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.archiver.ManifestConfiguration for 'useUniqueVersions'

Tags: maven, maven-jar-plugin

My Maven build fails with the error message:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) on project XXX: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar for parameter manifest: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.archiver.ManifestConfiguration for 'useUniqueVersions' -> [Help 1]`

The relevant section of my POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I can't find anything related to `useUniqueVersions`. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

Specify version `2.4` for the `maven-jar-plugin`.

Note: Why can't you see this configuration field? Your POM may inherit it. Always check the effective POM in such cases.